# Certain characters are not showing when opening digitalocean.com happening both Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts, ubuntu-14.04

Some characters are not showing when opening digitalocean.com  happening both Chrome and Firefox. 
Check the Screenshots below..
I am using ubuntu 14.04

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Start with checking the console errors:

> https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>   /assets/fonts/appicons-c630ae11.woff2?lujp4j:1 GET https://www.digitalocean.com/assets/fonts/appicons-c630ae11.woff2?lujp4j

It works fine in Chrome / Firefox here..